# Clustering the latent vector in an auto-encoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders

I have recently been learning about variational auto-encoders and their generative nature. I think I understand how they work and roughly understand their loss function which is:

$$E[logp_\theta(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z})] - D_{KL}[q_\phi(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{x})||N(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{1})]$$

In the loss function we consider KL divergence between a normal prior with zero mean and diagonal standard deviation and the latent distribution to enforce structure in our latent vector. This leads to the latent vector having roughly orthogonal basis which we can sample clearly identified low level features to produce high level data.

Now what I don't understand is why we can't do a similar thing in auto-encoders. We clearly don't enforce any loss on the latent vector and therefore it's not guaranteed to have orthogonal basis or any clear structure. Even though we don't specify a structure for this latent vector, by definition the auto-encoder will have to come up with some sort of structure for it to reproduce the input as best as possible.

So why can we not for example cluster the latent representations and find some relationships and low level features that way? Or perhaps we even have labelled data so we could build some sort of classifier on the latent vector to identify low level features?

Comment: What makes you think we can't cluster low-dimensional representations produced by an autoencoder?

Comment: It seems like an obvious thing to investigate but I couldn't find any literature/ blogs/ articles about anyone attempting to do this, so I assumed this is not something that would work for a reason I don't understand.

Comment: I think this blog post does what you're asking about:
https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/latent-space-representation-a-hands-on-tutorial-on-autoencoders-in-tensorflow-57735a1c0f3f